# When I try to save directly using the credential api, I get this error message

Tags: android, credentials, google-smartlockpasswords

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: The save prompt is disabled for the current app. To restore, remove this app from the “Never save” list in the Smart Lock for Passwords settings for all accounts on this device.

When I try to save directly using the credential api, I get this error message

“Never save” list can't be found anywhere

Answer (score 1):

1-Open Google Manage settings.

2-Select Security Tab.

[image]

3-Scroll down you can see Password Manager Click on it.
[image]
4-Setting icon on the top right click on it.
[image]
5-In Bottom there are Declined Apps and sites find your application and remove it.
[image]